# When looping over objects in a list, why does calling a method of a single object, cause changes to be applied to all objects in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following code, why does the second and third objects of the list receive the `c` parameter values even before their own method was called?

```
class a:
    c = {}
    
    def addC(self, key, error):
        self.c[key] = error

def main():
    i = 0
    aa = []
    while i < 3:
        aa.append(a())
        i += 1
    for idx, ab in enumerate(aa):
        ab.addC('try', idx)

main()
```

Here is a visualization of the problem:

[image: Problem visualisation]

As shown, for each object in the list, the `c` parameter after the first for loop iteration looks like this:

```
{'try': 0}
```

How can I achieve that the method changes only single objects `c` parameter value per call, when working in loop? i.e. on the first iteration `aa[0].c = {'try', 0}`, on the second iteration `aa[1].c = {'try', 1}`, and on the third iteration `aa[2].c = {'try', 2}`.

Comment: we cannot see it. could you post your code as formatted text?

Comment: Is `c` really intended to be a _class variable_, and not an _instance variable_? Do not get confused about doing it in a loop. It's not the direct cause. You can reproduce the problem outside of a loop. Try instantiating 2 `a` objects `a1` and `a2`, call `a1.addC(...)`, then see what happens to `a2.c`.

Comment: Guys you are right, c should be instance variable, not class variable. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a class variable. If you need the variable C for each object to have its own value, you should use this:

```
class a:
        def __init__(self):
            self.c = {}  # create instance variable
    
        def addC(self, key, error):
            self.c[key] = error
...
```